# Salesforce - Add If-Else statement in custom HTML email template in Lightning

Tags: javascript, salesforce, salesforce-lightning

I am trying to get an opportunity field values, perform some if-else statements and the result  to the email, the whole process thru JavaScript. I do not want to use VR, as there are many combinations which depend on the 3 inter-dependent-picklist values selected by the user.

Answer (score 0):

Since salesforce doesn't support if/else.
The best solution would be to use getters instead. Such as:

```
get subscribers() {
return 
this.trackedItems.username.value && this.trackedItems.username.role === "subscriber" 
? true 
: this.trackedItems.username.value && this.trackedItems.username.role === "admin" 
? false 
: false
}

HTML: 
<template if:true={subscribers}>...</template>
```

In this case, you check if the user is a subscriber and not an admin and then shows it.